# Codeigniter - retrieve parameter without controller name in URL

Tags: codeigniter, url, uri, codeigniter-url

I'm trying to retrieve string as parameter using following URL scheme:
www.myapp.com/[String]

Is there any way I can do this?

*Based on my research, Codeigniter doesn't accept string parameters unless I include the Controller's name in URL: www.myapp.com/[Controller Name]/[String]
But this doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: What's you problem. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, CI requires controller name at URI, but You can use default_controller.

At `config/routes.php` add route rule `$routes['(:any)']` = 'welcome/index';`, remove index.php from Your URL (there're many tutorials and how-to for this), and at last use`uri`class at Your`index()`method of`welcome` controller:

```
function index(){
    var_dump($this->uri->uri_string());
}
```

Comment: After following your instructions, and I type in "myapp.com/[String]", I get redirected to 404. I think it's still looking for the controller (instead of taking parameter)?